# Cordova - Scrolling causes fixed elements to flicker/blink

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap

I have tried every potential solution out there from

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

to

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden
```

but nothing seems to fix an element in a fixed position from flickering/blinking/dissapearing during a scroll on iOS with

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

As soon as the scroll stops, the divs come back.

Does anybody know what is wrong? I am using Cordova/PhoneGap

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the scroll an event somehow connected to the rendering? If so there may be a case of each time the scroll event occurs it re-renders the component.

I also found this blog post related to smoothing out rendering for Cordova. Hopefully, you find it helpful (you already tried one of their solutions). https://quickleft.com/blog/4-steps-to-minimizing-rendering-issues-in-cordova-applications/

Comment: I said component, sorry being working in React a lot. I just meant re-rendering parts of the DOM

Comment: This another article on optimizing Cordova apps, its done by Visual Studio. http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/better-web-performance/#dom

Comment: I have tried all of that but nothing seems to work. It is pretty much a fresh project with nothing but enough content to need a scroll bar and jQuery Mobile. It seems like a common problem with PhoneGap. Would it be worthwhile switching to React or Ionic?

Comment: Well, React is great... However, Ionic is I think more like Cordova in a sense and their documentation is pretty great too. If you are at all familiar with React Native though, it could be worth it.